# How to get user profile Image in big size from Twitter timeline object in iOS

Tags: ios, twitter

I use twitter API `fetchTimelineForUser:(NSString *)username` to fetch tweets timeline. The size of user profile image in this object is normal. But I need a bigger size image.

How can I accomplish this?

BTW, I don't want to fetch the user object from twitter.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see profile_image_url and profile_image_url_https  in user object, normal sized image is mostly 48px - 48px. By modifying the url you can get larger image.

For more info please [see this link](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/user-profile-images-and-banners).

Hope this helps.. :)

Answer (score 6):

In profile image url you are getting `_normal`, appended with the image name like `http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/2284174872/7df3h38zabcvjylnyfe3_normal.png`

To get actual image remove `_normal`. It will be `http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/2284174872/7df3h38zabcvjylnyfe3.png`